# ValueError: Data cardinality is ambiguous: in data size

Tags: arrays, tensorflow, return-value

I am an apprentice of this programming language that I am passionate about. I am trying to make a gcn model with the lines that I show you, however, I get the error:

Greetings, When writing and executing the following model, I get the error :
ValueError: Data cardinality is ambiguous:
x sizes: 95, 10
y sizes: 95
Make sure all arrays contain the same number of samples.

Could you guide me to identify the difficulty. I am grateful.

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np


# Define GCN model
def create_gcn_model(adjacency_dim, input_dim, hidden_units, num_heads):
    X_input = tf.keras.Input(shape=(adjacency_dim, input_dim), name='X_input')
    A_input = tf.keras.Input(shape=(adjacency_dim, adjacency_dim), name='A_input')

    # GCN layer
    gcn = GraphConvolution(hidden_units, num_heads)([X_input, A_input])
    gcn = tf.keras.layers.ReLU()(gcn)

    # Output layer
    output = tf.keras.layers.Dense(1)(gcn)

    model = tf.keras.Model(inputs=[X_input, A_input], outputs=output)
    return model


# Prepare dataset
def prepare_dataset(adjacency_matrix, time_series_data, num_timesteps):
    X_data = []
    y_data = []

    # Generate sliding windows 
    for i in range(len(time_series_data) - num_timesteps):
        X_data.append(time_series_data[i:i+num_timesteps])
        y_data.append(time_series_data[i+num_timesteps])

    X_data = np.array(X_data)
    y_data = np.array(y_data)

    adjacency_matrix = adjacency_matrix[:len(time_series_data), :len(time_series_data)]

    return X_data, y_data, adjacency_matrix


# Define evaluation metric 
def mse(y_true, y_pred):
    return tf.reduce_mean(tf.square(y_true - y_pred))

adjacency_dim = 10  # Dimension of the adjacency matrix
input_dim = 1  # Dimension of input features
hidden_units = 64  # Number of hidden units in the GCN layer
num_heads = 2  # Number of attention heads
num_timesteps = 5  # Number of previous time steps to consider

adjacency_matrix = np.random.rand(adjacency_dim, adjacency_dim)
time_series_data = np.random.rand(100, input_dim)

X_data, y_data, adjacency_matrix = prepare_dataset(adjacency_matrix, time_series_data, num_timesteps)

# Creating model
model = create_gcn_model(adjacency_dim, input_dim, hidden_units, num_heads)
model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='mse', metrics=['mse'])
```